# ESRI GEodatabase - LRS Metadata. Where to find it using SQL?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, enterprise-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase, linear-referencing

Prior, (I can confirm in version 2.4), I could check the LRS metadata using a query to the LRS_METADATA table in a Enterprise geodatabase.

I used to have this script

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import arcpy
import os

arcpy.env.workspace = r""
arcpy.env.workspace = r"U:\Documents\ArcGIS\Projects\UPDM2018\UPDM2018_DataOwner.sde"

def is_table_in_LRS(tablename):
   with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(os.path.join(arcpy.env.workspace, "LRS_METADATA"), ['Metadata']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        raw_metadata = row[0].tobytes()

    xml = str(raw_metadata.decode("utf-8"))

    root = ET.fromstring(xml)
    event_tables = [elem.get('TableName') for elem in root.iter('EventTable')]
    print(event_tables)
    return tablename in event_tables

res = is_table_in_LRS("MyTable")
print(res)
```

Using ArcGIS Pro 2.9, I added an event table to my LRS, and tried the script above, but as result i just got the list of event tables without the new one.

after restarting ArcGIS pro, my Ide, checking the properties of the LRS and the properties of the Feature class, i was pulling my hair because the visual information from ArcGIS pro was correct, but the information from the script was not.

After making a double check in the documentation, I found [here](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.9/help/production/location-referencing-pipelines/alrs-data-model.htm), that I can get the lrs metadata using the `arcpy.Describe` method.

Then I proceed to modified the script:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import arcpy
import os

arcpy.env.workspace = r""
arcpy.env.workspace = r"U:\Documents\ArcGIS\Projects\UPDM2018\UPDM2018_DataOwner.sde"

def is_table_in_LRS(tablename):
    desc = arcpy.Describe(os.path.join(arcpy.env.workspace, "UPDM2018.Dataowner.P_Integrity\\UPDM2018.Dataowner.ALRS"))

    xml = desc.lrsMetadata
    
    root = ET.fromstring(xml)
    event_tables = [elem.get('TableName') for elem in root.iter('EventTable')]
    print(event_tables)
    return tablename in event_tables

res = is_table_in_LRS("MyTable")
print(res)
```

I want to know, where it is stored? I would like to make this script but in SQL, where should I look for the REAL Lrs metadata?

For this modification is required to know the name of the LRS, in the example above the name is **"ALRS"** and it is located in the dataset **"P_Integrity"**. that information used to be also in the LRS_METADATA table. So far I have it hardcoded, but I require to make this part dynamic too.

Answer (score 0):

The information that is required was moved to the GDB_ITEMS table, it can be fetched with a cursor:

```
identifier = None
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(os.path.join(arcpy.env.workspace,"sde.GDB_ITEMTYPES"), ['UUID'], where_clause="Name = 'Location Referencing Dataset'") as type_items_cursor:
        for type_object in type_items_cursor:
            identifier = type_object[0]
del type_items_cursor

lrs_path = None
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(os.path.join(arcpy.env.workspace,"sde.GDB_ITEMS"), ['Path'], where_clause=f"Type = '{identifier}'") as items_cursor:
        for item in items_cursor:
            lrs_path = item[0]
del items_cursor
print(lrs_path)
```